# Can xsd be ambiguous?

Tags: parsing, xsd

I always considered XSD as a way to specify an XML-file's grammar. Now I stumbled upon something like this in a real-world XSD spec:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" 
           xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" 
           elementFormDefault="qualified" 
           attributeFormDefault="unqualified">
    <xs:element name="parser-killer">
        <xs:complexType>
          <xs:sequence minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded">
              <xs:element name="element" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0"/>
          </xs:sequence>
        </xs:complexType>
    </xs:element>
</xs:schema>
```

The problem here is, that one cannot decide for an empty input, e.g.

```
<parser-killer>
</parser-killer>
```

whether the XML contains an empty sequence, or a sequence of empty contents. 
This may not be a problem for the human eye, but if one tries to generate a parser from this file, it may end up looping forever (collecting infinitely many empty elements).

Is that simply abuse of XSD or is it required to "sanitize" any given XSD before code generation?

Comment: Why are you talking about code generation in your final sentence? The XML Schema specification did not have 'code generation' as one of its design goals. There may be tools that can do that, but it depends on which tool how they do things, so you need to ask that last  question specific to a particular tool.

Answer (score 0):

XML Schema validators are in no way required to "generate a parser". It's allowed of course, but it's an implementation details. In fact many don't, they build up an internal representation of the schema and interpret it to validate the file against the schema.

To find out if you example input document with the empty `<parser-killer>` element is valid or not, a validator does not *need* to know whether this element should be interpreted as:

- zero or any number sequences of zero children named `<element>`
- an infinite number of sequences of zero children named `<element>`
- zero sequences of a hundred children named `<element>`

It's not relevant - it just needs to know whether the content of `<parser-killer>` has at least one path in the model group.

There's an easy rule-of-thumb that you *could* apply in a validator: if there are no element children and there is a sequence (or choice, or all) with `minOccurs="0"`, then this is assumed to be the reason why the content of the parent is valid. That will stop the validator from looping infinitely in this situation.

### Unique Particle Attribution

To be clear, the reason that there is no problem is that there is no ambiguity how the schema validated an element - because there is no element. So it's okay to have an ambiguity like this between a model group and a particle declaration - it's not okay to have an ambiguity between particle declarations; it needs to be clear by which unique path through the model group it was that the validator arrived at the particle. 
But that is not the problem in the situation that you describe.